# Linear algebra exam questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Pick out the true statements:

1. There exist $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with real entries such that $(I-(AB-BA)^n) = 0$.
2. If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite matrix then $tr(A)^n\geq n^n \det(A)$. 
   :(

I am stucked, unable to solve this problem.

Comment: For the second part, consider a scalar matrix.

Comment: are you sure the second one is not $tr(A)^n \geq n^n det(A)$?

Comment: do both $n$ in the first statement refer to the same natural number? is this first statement supposed to be true for all $n$ or for some $n$?

Comment: ya sir both refers  to the same natural number

Comment: For (1), consider matrices $A$ and $B$ where $B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: @joel it is working that mean first statement is true

Comment: @JoelCornett: But then $(AB-BA)^n=0$ and the equation is $I=0$, which is wrong...

Comment: @NickKidman: yeah I just realized that. Disregard.

Comment: ya nick kidman is right. hope to get a solution of the first part

Comment: Long time back I asked these questions where I used to use "pick out .." At the time I was new to this website. But today I am getting negative votes without mentioning any reason. It is something heartening me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first statement, if $n=2$, let $A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$

Then

$$AB-BA= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}& +\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$

I think this can be generalized to $2m \times 2m$ matrices by using

$\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 & 0& ..&0 \\
0 & A & 0& ..&0 \\
. & .& . & ..& . \\
0 & 0 & 0& ..&A \\\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} B & 0 & 0& ..&0 \\
0 & B & 0& ..&0 \\
. & .& . & ..& . \\
0 & 0 & 0& ..&B \\\end{pmatrix}$

For the second statement $A=I$...

If the problem asks instead to prove that

$$tr(A)^n \geq n^n \det(A)$$

then let $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues. Then they are real and positive (WHY?), thus by $AM-GM$ we have:

$$\frac{tr(A)}{n}=\frac{\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{\lambda_1 \cdot ... \lambda_n}=\sqrt[n]{\det(A)}$$

Comment: sir nick kidman has given counter example for second statement then how can it be true?

Comment: Well $A=I$ is a counterexample ;)

Comment: For the first one, I think i am wrong. Actually, if $A,B$ are $2 \times 2$, then $(AB-BA)^2= [tr(AB-BA)] (AB-BA)-\det(AB-BA)I_2$. Thus all you need is to find two matrices $A,B$ so that $\det(AB-BA)=-1$.

Comment: Here both statements are wrong?

Comment: Well not sure about the first one ;)

Comment: Also for the second one, I pointed in my message that a very closely related statement is true.... Are you sure there isn't an extra $n$ in your statement?

Comment: i need a proper justification for the first statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3395/discussion-between-srijan-and-n-s)

Comment: @srijan I constructed an example for 2 by 2 matrices

Comment: what is that sir? Post it as an answer.

Comment: @NS can you give me proof for the second part. I just checked it is same what you were writing $(tr(A)^n$

Comment: @srijan I edited my answer to address both questions....

Comment: sincerely thanks to you sir..and everyone who took pain to devote time..and i apologize for misprinting second statement..but still i got many counter examples for that....that will be fruitfull for me

Answer (score 1):

For the second question: Consider the matrix $A=\text{diag}(a,b)$, then the relation is $a+b\ge 4 ab$. It's trivial to construct a counterexample, e.g. $a=b=1$. More concretely, all $a,b$ with $a>\frac{1}{4}$ and $b>\frac{a}{4a-1}$ violate the inequality.

(I cleared the answer for the first one, which was flawed.)

Comment: Yours first part is not clear to me. Can you explain me please?

Comment: I don't think it is in general true that $[A,B]^2=I\Rightarrow[A,B] = \pm I$, consider the matrix $\frac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 4 & -3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Actually i was not clear about the notation. Now its clear to me

Comment: In your answer, you write that "If $[A,B]^2 = I$ then $[A,B] = \pm I$". I'm just seeking some clarification on that part since it's not true.

Comment: @EuYu: Yeah, you're right, I don't know how to resove it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question.

For $n$ even, this is certainly true. Every traceless matrix can be written as the commutator of two square matrices. That is, given $C$ such that $tr(C) = 0$, there exists $A,B$ such that $[A,B]=AB - BA=C$. Now for even $n$ we can take the diagonal matrix $$D = diag(1,-1,1,-1,\cdots,1,-1)$$ which can be written in terms of some $A,B$. Then we have $AB - BA = D$ which implies the equation.

For odd $n$, if we can show the existence of a traceless $n$th root of the identity, then we can certainly prove the statement.

Edit: I'm  not too familiar with real canonical forms, so someone might be able to correct me. Take the complex diagonal matrix with the diagonals given by the $n$th roots of unity. Would taking the real canonical form of such a matrix give us the desired $nth$ root traceless matrix?

Comment: For odd $n$, $(AB-BA)^n=I$ implies that $1$ is an eigenvalue for $AB-BA$ which might lead to issues or not :D